# Doctype is breaking some of my css but not all

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

Hi I am wondering about the use of !DOCTYPE html

I created a simple web page that ran fine on all browsers except IE.
On researching the issue it suggested I use !DOCTYPE html. This however seems to negate some of my CSS but not all of it.

I looked into it and the only advice I could find was about mis matched spellings between my id tags and the .css # tags.

I have a tiny piece of java script that still works fine. My 2 divs work fine which allows the user to scroll while the submit button stays on screen.

But I lose my CSS for the table and the home button. Its all wrapped up in some old school asp that may be contributing to the problem as I have previously only used asp.net

```
<%
    Set Cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Cn.Open CnString
    ' Build Sql.
    Sql = "SELECT [USER_CODE],[WINDOWS_ID], [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME], [ACTIVE_IND] FROM      FSUSER ORDER BY [LAST_NAME]"
    ' Open recordset.
    Set Rs = Cn.Execute(Sql)
    If Not Rs.Eof Then arrayActiveUsers = Rs.GetRows()
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    Response.Write "<form action='main1.asp' method='post'>"
    Response.Write "<div id=""top"">"
    Response.Write "<button name=""regions1"" type=""submit"" value="&regions&" >Save_"&regions&"</button>"
    Response.Write "<a href=""default.asp"" id=""home"" onclick=""return confirm('Have you saved your changes before leaving this page?');"" >Home</a>"
        Response.Write "</div>"
        Response.Write "<div id=""bottom"">"
        Response.Write "<table id=""table1"">"
        Response.Write "<tr>"
        Response.Write "<td>User Code</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>Windows ID</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>First Name</td>"
        Response.Write "<td> Last Name</td>"
        Response.Write "<td> Status</td>"
        Response.Write "<td> ACTIVATE</td>"
        Response.Write "<td> DE-ACTIVATE</td>"
        Response.Write "</tr>"

        Response.Write "<tr>"
For j = 0 To UBound(arrayActiveUsers,2)
if arrayActiveUsers(4,j) = 1 then
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(0,j) & "</td>" 
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(1,j) & "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(2,j) & "</td> "
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(3,j) & "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td ><font color=""green"">Active</font></td>" 
        Response.Write "<td></td>" 
        Response.Write "<td><input type=""checkbox"" name=""active"" value="  & arrayActiveUsers(0,j) &" /></td>"

Response.Write "</tr>"  
else    
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(0,j) & "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(1,j) & "</td>" 
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(2,j) & "</td> " 
        Response.Write "<td>" & arrayActiveUsers(3,j) & "</td>"
        Response.Write "<td><font color=""red"">Not Active</font></td>" 
        Response.Write "</td>" & "<td><input type=""checkbox"" name=""de- active"" value=" & arrayActiveUsers(0,j) &"  /></td>" 
        Response.Write "<td></td>"

        Response.Write "</tr>"
end if
next
Response.Write "</table>"
Response.Write "</div>"
Response.Write "</form>"
 Cn.Close
 Set Cn = Nothing
 %>
```

So this is the header of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main1.css">
<TITLE> Main </TITLE>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function greeting(){
                alert("Have you commited all your data?")
            }
      </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
```

and this is the css:

```
#top{
top:0;
position:fixed;
background: white;
}

#bottom{
margin-top:40px;
}

#home{
display: inline;
width: 115px;
height: 24px;
background: #E6E6E6;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center; 
border-width:2px;
border-style:ridge; 
border-color: gray;
color: black;    
}

#table1{
padding:3;
border:groove,2px,#f0f0f0;
background-color:a0a0a0;

}
```

I apologise for any glaring errors that I haven't spotted. I'm aware that the CSS will look differntly on IE to the rest but I if someone if I could get it working maybe I can create 2 style sheets one for IE one for everything else.

I should add I have tried multiple doctypes all to the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to help if you could create a jsfiddle with your final html so we can test it, the problem could be some bad css coding or a html tag that is not properly closed.

Some brief comment about the doctype: DOCTYPE declaration is *always* required. If you don't write it then the browsers will render the site in different ways since they don't know which standards to apply (specially IE), so you will see your styles fine in your working browser but in other browsers your site will look terrible. Considering that, fixing the styles will probably made you rewrite all of your css since you wrote it with a bad standard (it's like building a house on pure sand).

Comment: Using Fiddle I worked out my issue.
Thanks so much for the advice :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know wether this is the cause for the problem, but `<!DOCTYPE html>` seems to be HTML5 only and I'm not sure that is what you want.

For HTML4  for best compatibility when not using frames try

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The solution I chose:

1. I went over all the pages in the site and instead of declaring the DOCTYPE for each page I created a single include file (doctype.asp)
2. The content of this file is

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html >
   <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8         lt-ie7" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gt IE 8] ><!--> <html class="no-js" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> <!--<![endif]-->
   ```
3. Now when the whole site has the same DOCTYPE declaration i fixed any issues with the CSS.